# Typescript StackNavigatonProps and Screen props in react-navigation v5

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, expo

What is the best way to define type for screen's `navigation` prop, when screen is in different file that router? Let's say I have one file, in which I define routes:

```
//Router.tsx

type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Profile: undefined;
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

// Component rendering navigator
const Router = () => {
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Then I have the separate file for screen:

```
// Home.tsx


// here has to be the same RootStackParamList
// that we've already defined in Router.tsx
type = HomeScreenNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<
  RootStackParamList,
  "Home"
>;

type Props: {
  navigation: HomeScreenNavigationProp
}


const Home = ({navigation}: Props) => {
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Do I have to copy `RootStackParamList` over and over to every screen or create something like `types.ts` file and import it from there?  Is there a better way to handle it? I am using `navigation` almost in every component.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
type RootStackComponent<RouteName extends keyof RootStackParamList> = React.FC<{
  navigation: StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, RouteName>,
  route: RouteProp<RootStackParamList, RouteName>
}>
```

```
const Home: RootStackComponent<'Home'> = ({ navigation, route }) => {}
```

Comment: Is the syntax of this correct? I am getting an "Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effect" error

Comment: braces are missing. Correct one:

type RootStackComponent<RouteName extends keyof RootStackParamList> = React.FC<{
  navigation: StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, RouteName>
  route: RouteProp<RootStackParamList, RouteName>
}>

Answer (score 0):

First define your createStackNavigator type like so:

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
     Home: undefined;
     Register: undefined;
     Login: undefined;
};
const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
```

Then go to Home.tsx component and add this line:

```
type Props = StackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Home'>;

const Home = ({navigation, route}: Props) => {
 .
 .
 . 
}
```

Reference: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/